# ERROR: expected package `Juno [e5e0dc1b]` to be registered

Tags: installation, package, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I just downloaded JuliaPro 1.5.3 and am trying to follow this tutorial exactly: [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei-xnVid3QY&ab_channel=TheJuliaProgrammingLanguage). But when I went into Atom and attempted to update the packages like so

```
(@JuliaPro_v1.5.3-1) pkg> up
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: expected package `Juno [e5e0dc1b]` to be registered
```

I don’t understand what this means…How do I get Juno "registered" so that I can resolve this and continue on with the tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting the registries folder within my .julia folder. Then from the REPL, I went into Package mode and entered `update`. It then re-downloaded all of the contents from the registries folder and updated everything. Once the registries folder was re-downloaded, I was able to install XLSX using the commands `using Pkg` followed by `Pkg.add("XLSX")`...so I guess the registries folder got corrupted when it was originally installed?